# Wheel axle too short on the fork

Tags: fork, hub, quick-release

I think my front wheel axle is too short, it is only half the size of the fork notch, see the picture:

[image]

But if I remove the nut, the fork would touch the wheel and the disc brake.

When I insert the quick release axle it looks like this:

[image]

**Is there something wrong, or it is okay?**

Comment: when you insert the wheel in the fork - do you need to widen the forkstays or the wheel fits there without any problems? Is it aluminium fork, steel or carbon, by the way? Can you measure the distance between the outer faces of the nuts on the axle?

Comment: @Mike  The wheel fits there without any problems. They are all steel. Sorry, I can't measure it.

Comment: I've checked some pictures in the internet and I think it's pretty normal, still your forkends are quite wide while the QR axle is suitable also for thinner forkends. Nevertheless, once I'm home I'll check my bicycles for the measurements. What kind of bike is it? Road, hybrid, mountain?

Comment: Perfectly normal. There is no need for the axle to sit flush with the outside surfaces of the drop-outs. In fact it would interfere with the proper functioning of the quick releases. Note on the side: The second picture doesn't show the little conical spring. Make sure to have them in place. And to close the QR properly.

Comment: It is a 20 inch folding e-bike. To much problems, and the electric part doesn't work, I have returned it. 
  
 https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072N1NCZP/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is counter-intuitive but the axle is not holding the wheel onto the bike.  That's the job of the skewer and Quick Release.

The axle is in the dropout to hold the weight of the bike from above - your photos are from below.  The axle also provides support for the surfaces where the bearings and therefore the wheel run.  So almost all the time, the axle is under compression forces.

Personally I'd expect to see a little more metal there, but that part should be fully functional as-is.

Possible causes its a real weight-weenie bike where every gram counts, or the wheel is from another bike/fork which had a different thickness of dropout, or its just a cheap bike saving on materials.